# How To Push Biggest Numbers To The Back Of Array

Tags: c

How do I make it so after the first pass, the largest number is guaranteed to be in the highest-numbered element of the array; after the second pass, the two highest numbers are “in place,” and so on.

The current code only makes it pass from largest to smallest but I do not want that.

I'm only trying to do this for the data items in original order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    int a[SIZE] = {2, 6, 4, 8, 10, 12, 89, 68, 45, 37};
    int noc = 0;

    puts("Data items in original order");

    for (int noc = 0; noc < 9; noc++) {
        printf("\n");

        for (size_t i = 0; i + noc < SIZE; i++) {
            printf("%4d", a[i]);
        }
        for (int pass = 1; pass < SIZE; pass++) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE - pass; i++) {
                if (a[i] > a[i - 1]) {
                    int hold = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[i - 1];
                    a[i - 1] = hold;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int pass = 1; pass < SIZE; pass++) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE - pass; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                int hold = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = hold;
            }
        }
    }

    puts("\nData items in ascending order");

    for (size_t i = 0; i + noc < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%4d", a[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: Do they have to be in ascending order one at a time each pass?

Comment: This is a well known sorting method known as "Bubble Sort". You can find a pseudocode implementation here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: It sounds like you're maybe describing a variation on Selection Sort.  Quite simply, you use your inner loop to scan the appropriate range searching for the index of any value larger than the one at the desired position, and then after the loop, if you found it, you swap those two values.

Comment: And for the next highest, you can code it as though the array is one element shorter.

Comment: each pass you go through the elements of the array, find the max and store it index, when you finish scanning all elements, replace the first (or last) element by your max (knowing that your stored it's index and value), then do the same thing for the second element...

Comment: Paddy is right. Bubble sort will change order of elements besides the ones that eventually move to the end. It at least appears that the OP wants a sequence like: `2 1 4 3 6 5` to appear as `2 1 4 3 5 6` after first pass. Bubble sort won't do that. It will have `1 2 3 4 5 6` after first pass. That, assuming the OPs description of *"I'm only trying to do this for the data items in original order"* means keep the order and shift everything down to make space for the largest element at the end. It isn't exactly crystal clear *what* that statement actually means, so clarifying would be helpful.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this incrementally instead of just calling `qsort` on the array and be done with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 10
int main(void)
{
int a[SIZE] = {2, 6, 4, 8, 10, 12, 89, 68, 45, 37};
int i;
int pass = 0;
while(pass < SIZE - 1){
int index = SIZE - pass - 1;
int MAX = a[index];
for(i=0;i<SIZE - pass;i++){
if(a[i]>MAX) {
    MAX = a[i];
    index = i;
}
}
a[index] = a[SIZE - pass - 1];
a[SIZE - pass - 1] = MAX;
for(i=0 ;i < SIZE ; i++ ) printf("%d ",a[i]);
printf("\n");
pass++;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use several sort algorithm for that

1. shellsort
2. bubblesort ( slowest alg )
3. heapsort
4. insertion sort
5. tree sort
6. QuickSort

There are a lot of sort algo that placed the integer asc or desc

Comment: The asker is actually describing Selection Sort

Comment: @KevinWang the asker can use any sort alg if he is only interested in that the biggest number is at the end ;) thanks for -1

Comment: The asker asked: "How do I make it so after the first pass, the largest number is guaranteed to be in the highest-numbered element of the array; after the second pass, the two highest numbers are “in place,” and so on."

Insertion sort will not do this.  Bubblesort will not do this.  Tree sort will not do this.  Quicksort does not really have sequential iterations.  Selection sort is literally the name for the sorting algorithm wherein the i-th biggest/smallest element is in its correct position after the i-th iteration, but it was not mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @KevinWang *"Bubblesort will not do this"* - um.. bubble-sort *will* do this. What it will *not* be guaranteed to do is retain the original ordering for all remaining elements, which at-least *seems* to be important to the OP.